# What it happens when you pass multiple column names to the `add_index` method?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Index for multiple columns in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048909/index-for-multiple-columns-in-activerecord)

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and MySQL. I would like to know what are differences (at the database level) between these [`add_index`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) method statements:

```
add_index :database_table_name, [:column_one_name]
add_index :database_table_name, [:column_one_name, :column_two_name]
```

What it happens when you specify more than one column name (`:column_one_name, :column_two_name` instead of `:column_one_name`)?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048909/index-for-multiple-columns-in-activerecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Nazariy: The answer is complete without following the link.  The link merely provides further information.

Comment: @eggyal, no, the answer is not complete - as it doesn't explain *how* to create a composite index. Remember that S/O questions are googleable by other (possibly very inexperienced) people looking for help on the same topic. Perhaps you could include the "how" in your answer to help them too...

Comment: @TarynEast: The question is asking "what happens if I do such and such".  The how is in the question.  My answer to "what happens if..." is complete.